# Does Proliferate work with Energy Counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can a players Energy Counters be increased using Proliferate?

This seems like it would be the case, as Poison Counters seem to work in a similar way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, like poison and experience counters before them players get energy counters, and proliferate can add an additional counter of a type a player has.

> When [Thriving Rhino](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThriving%20Rhino%5d) enters the battlefield, you get {E}{E} (two energy counters).

This means that 2 energy counters are placed on you when you play a Thriving Rhino.

> **121.1.** A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. Counters are not objects and have no characteristics. Notably, a counter is not a token, and a token is not a counter. Counters with the same name or description are interchangeable.
>
> **701.25a** To proliferate means to choose any number of permanents and/or players that have a counter, then give each exactly one additional counter of a kind that permanent or player already has.